# Mongoose: update Array with item-wise maximum

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

#### In Mongoose, how can I update an Array property with item-wise max, and have default `null` upon instantiation?

I have a Mongodb collection of timeseries where values are stored in a fixed-length array (1 item per minute, 1 document per day).

```
{
  'series': '#1',
  'values': [null, null, 1, 2, 3, -4, ... ] //24h*60min=1440 items
}
```

I am doing computations on ~x000 timeseries on a rather high frequency (100ms), and I want to store the maximum that each of these series met during every minute. For some reason, when I update the documents, Mongoose transforms the `.values` property into an object, which is more space-consuming and less efficient for my use.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test_db');

const TestSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  series: String,
  values: {type: Array, default: Array(5).fill(null), required: true},
});
const Test = mongoose.model('Test', TestSchema);

async function update({series, values}){ //called every minute or so
    let updated = {    };
    for (let {i, v} of values)  {
        if (updated[`values.${i}`] && updated[`values.${i}`]<v) updated[`values.${i}`]= v;
        if (!updated[`values.${i}`]) updated[`values.${i}`]=v;
    };

    return mongoose.connection.models.Test.updateOne(
        {'series':series},
        {   '$max': updated },
        { upsert: true, strict: true, new: true}
    );
}

async function test_update(){
    //get rid of previous tentatives
    await mongoose.connection.models.Test.deleteMany({});
    let s = new Test({series: '#1'});
    await update({series:'#1', values:[{i:3, v:-3},{i:4, v:6},{i:2, v:4}, {i:2, v:7}]});
}

test_update();
```

I would want my script to return

```
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cb351d9d615cd456bd6a4ed"),
    "series" : "#1",
    "__v" : 0,
    "values" : [null, null, 7, -3, 6]
}
```

and not the current result below:

```
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cb351d9d615cd456bd6a4ed"),
    "series" : "#1",
    "__v" : 0,
    "values" : { //values is an Object, not an Array
        "2" : 7,
        "3" : -3,
        "4" : 6
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did my suggestion work for you?

Answer (score 1):

`I **THINK** it may be your schema

Instead of:

```
const TestSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  series: String,
  values: {type: Array, default: Array(5).fill(null), required: true},
});
```

You should make `values` an array of numbers like this

```
const TestSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  series: String,
  values: {type: [Number], default: Array(5).fill(null), required: true},
});
```

Comment: I realize I tried your suggestion with `[Array]` instead of `Array`. First one didn't work I'll try yours tomorrow and will keep you posted!

Comment: Ok cool, just to make sure. I’m saying try `[Number]` not `Array`

Comment: Nope. I ended up using a dict `{1: , 2: , 3: }` but that's crap. Please let me know if you find a better solution.